# Is there a way to get the model name from a mongoose model instance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I´m using mongoose and I need to find a model name from a model instance.

In one part of the code I have:

```
 const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        phone: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }

const schema = new mongoose.Schema('MyData', schema);

let instance = new this({
      name: 'Pete',
      phone: '123'
});
```

Ths instance variable is passed around in my code. Later I need to find out instance name, but I´m no sure if there is a way to do it, something like:

```
let instanceName = getInstanceName(instance); <== Expects 'MyData' to be returned
```

Is that possible using mongoose ?

Comment: Have you tried using this `instance.constructor.modelName`?

Comment: I´ve tried with no sucess, but seens that what I did it wrong. It´s working properly with `instance.constructor.modelName`.Thanks.

Comment: Can I post it as an answer so you could accept it as the correct one? Thanks. :)

Comment: Sure. You should.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The name of the model can be accessed using this `instance.constructor.modelName`.

Answer (score 24):

I realized I had a model not an instance of a model so I needed to use something else.

If you have a model, you can get the name as below:

```
const model = mongoose.model("TestModel", schema);
const collectionName = model.collection.collectionName;
```

If you have a specific item/instance of the model:

```
const instance = new model({...});
const collectionName = instance.constructor.modelName
```

as Hannah posted.

Comment: That's the collection name, not the model name. The model name is model.modelName

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was looking for how to get a **[discriminator](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html)** model name from a mongoose model, and the suggested solutions didn't work:

```
const PerformanceResult = DropDown.discriminator('PerformanceResult', new db.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true }
}))
export default PerformanceResult
```

---

```
console.log(PerformanceResult.constructor.modelName) // undefined
console.log(PerformanceResult.collection.collectionName) // DropDown (parent name)
```

you can use this:

```
console.log(PerformanceResult.modelName) // PerformanceResult
```

> mongoose version: "^5.11.8"