# Accessing the name of a class as a string in JavaScript when class was created using another constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to print the name of a class that is being used to create a new object, but running into an issue because the class is a mongoose model that was created using `mongoose.model()`:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const genreSchema = mongoose.Schema({ name: String });
const Genre = mongoose.model("Genre", genreSchema);

async function create(Model, modelInfo) {
  const instance = new Model(modelInfo);
  // Await some asynchronous work
  console.log(instance.constructor.name, "created: ", instance);
}

create(Genre, { name: "Thriller" });
```

When doing `console.log(instance.constructor.name)`, the result is *model*. I was hoping for *Genre*, but I'm guessing this happens because `constructor` in this case is referring to the constructor for the Genre class (prototype chaining I believe), which is model (`mongoose.model()`).

If I try `console.log(Genre.constructor.name)` the result is *function* (which I am guessing refers to the constructor of the `mongoose.model()`), and `console.log(Genre.name)` yields *model* as well. `console.log(instance.name)` of course yields *Thriller*.

Anybody know how I can get it to print out *Genre*?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47040333/438992

Comment: According to the linked question: `instance.constructor.modelName`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899574/what-is-the-difference-between-typeof-and-instanceof-and-when-should-one-be-used

Comment: Can you check this it will solve your problem what exactly are you looking for
https://github.com/airrakeshkumarsharma/boilerplat/blob/master/src/repository/base.ts